# URL REWRITING : Redirect a link to the new

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am a beginner in the REWRITING URL and in fact I replaced this link `http://www.downisynet.rf.gd/article.php?id=14` with `http://www.downisynet.rf.gd/tutoriel/14`

Yet both links are still accessible.

So I want to know how to redirect the old URL to the new one?

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^tutoriel-([0-9]+)   article.php?tutoriel=$1 [L]
```

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: What do you mean by "Yet both links are still accessible"?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply 301 redirect one page to another using .htaccess. Add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /article.php?id=14 http://www.downisynet.rf.gd/tutoriel/14
```

Comment: @CamilleRakoto if it works for you please accept the answer as correct.

Comment: if i upload another tutorial, must I Always do the same code ? For example : Redirect 301 /article.php?id=15 http://www.downisynet.rf.gd/tutoriel/15

Comment: It's not working, it Always redirect to the old URL

Comment: Did you remove any other redirect code you had? It should just redirect the first URL stated to the second.

Comment: @CamilleRakoto post your full .htaccess code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Modified rule for /tutoriel/any-digit to /article.php?tutoriel=any-digit

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^tutoriel\/([0-9]+)$   /article.php?tutoriel=$1 [L]
```